# How can you print a Java array in neat columns using Graphics?

Tags: java, arrays, string, graphics, string-formatting

I am trying to create a function that takes a java array and the number of elements per row and returns the formatted string to be displayed. Here is my code:

```
public String displayArray(double [] arr, int numPerRow) {
        String formatted = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i % numPerRow != 0) {
                formatted += String.format("%8.1f ", arr[i]);
            } else {
                formatted += String.format("%n%8.1f ", arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return formatted;
    }
```

When I use println, I recieve the desired output:

```
    87.7     72.2     83.4     28.3     69.0     53.3     28.0     16.6     49.7     63.4 
    86.2     17.4     48.9     83.0     81.0     54.3     31.0     47.7     58.7      8.6 
    64.0     96.8     47.7      0.7     39.1     22.9     53.6     10.1     75.8      2.5
```

However, when I display text to the text field, I get this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5VqA.png]

The formatting gets messed up after a number with a different amount of digits is introduced. Does anyone know any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting the font of the text area to a mono-spaced font?

Comment: Alternatively, use leading zeros (`%08.1f`).

Comment: @Socowi I am currently

Comment: @user2478398 no I havent. What does that do?

Comment: @AdityaS No, you are using `%8.1f` to print leading *spaces*. I suggested `%08.1f` (note the `0`).

Comment: @Socowi my bad, didn't notice that. That works, as in the output lines up, but I wanted to know if there was solution where I could have leading spaces instead. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yeah, there is one: Use a font in which spaces have the same width as numbers – as suggested by user2478398.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide the approved comments as an actual answer:

Use a font with mono-spaced characters.

The problem here (as pointed out by @Socowi in the comments) is that the spaces are of different sizes to the numbers (and the numbers may not all be the same size, it's difficult to tell from the screenshot of the font), which means that on lines with fewer numeric digits (i.e. containing numbers below 10) there is a 'drift' in the font for the text area, but *not* when output to console (which typically *already* use a mono-spaced font).